# Not able to call WCF using ajax call

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, wcf

i am new to WCF and have created a WCFand named it as CategoryMasterWCF.svc file  with iCategoryMasterWCF.cs having following codes

```
namespace InfraERP.WebServices
{
// NOTE: You can use the "Rename" command on the "Refactor" menu to change the interface name "ICategoryMasterWCF" in both code and config file together.
[ServiceContract]
public interface ICategoryMasterWCF
{
    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped, RequestFormat= WebMessageFormat.Json)]
    string DoWork();

    [OperationContract]
    [WebGet]
    [WebInvoke(ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped, RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
    string sting(int id);

}


}
```

and  CategoryMasterWCF.svc.cs having code as follows

```
namespace InfraERP.WebServices
{
// NOTE: You can use the "Rename" command on the "Refactor" menu to change the class name "CategoryMasterWCF" in code, svc and config file together.
 [AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode
= AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Allowed)]
public class CategoryMasterWCF : ICategoryMasterWCF
{

   public string DoWork()
    {
        return "Hello, It Worked! ";
    }

    public string sting(int id)
    {
        string _sting = "Number is " +id.ToString();
        return _sting;
    }

}
}
```

and then i have added code in my aspx as follows

```
 $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: '../WebServices/CategoryMasterWCF.svc/sting',
        contentType: "application/json; charset=UTF-8; charset-uf8",
        data: {id:"1"},
        processData: true,
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (msg) {
            alert(msg);
        },
        error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert(textStatus + "---" + errorThrown);
        }
    });
```

The error coming is "unsupported media type".

i am not an expert in WCF or Asp.net. And i have searched a lot in the web and also in stackoverflow, and tested with the changes provided, but found no good result. Currently i have not made any changes in the web config. please help me to find a way out.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try removing contentType and dataType from ajax call?

Comment: Yes but it didn't helped.:(

Answer (score 0):

What's the `[WebGet]` attribute doing above the `sting` method? You're supposed to use either one of those (WebGet for Http GET and WebInvoke for the rest with POST as default). Since you're doing a `POST` request in your website you can remove it.

Also convert the data you are sending to a JSON string:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: '../WebServices/CategoryMasterWCF.svc/sting',
    contentType: "application/json; charset=UTF-8; charset-uf8",
    data: JSON.stringify({id:"1"}),
    processData: true,
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (msg) {
        alert(msg);
    },
    error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        alert(textStatus + "---" + errorThrown);
    }
});
```